# Error at using map in the following code

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, final

```
List<Double> NormalizedData = Doublevalues1.stream().map(n -> (((((n-min)/(max-min)))*2)-1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

here `max` and `min` are of `double` data type

my error starts in the line can any one help me in this regard

the error is "local variables referenced from lambda expression must be final or effectively final"

Comment: Note, in Java variables are **always** in `camelCase` - `PascalCase` is reserved for `class`es. Please stick to Java naming conventions, especially when posting on public fora, where people as accustomed to such conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you should define `min` and `max` as `final` before using them in the labmda expression:

```
final double min = // some value
final double max = // some other value
List<Double> NormalizedData = 
    Doublevalues1.stream()
                 .map(n -> (((((n-min)/(max-min)))*2)-1))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: They only need to _effectively_ `final`. Although making them as `final` would have the nice side-effect of indicating where the OP is reassigning.

Comment: They could be effective final instead.

Comment: it does nt works as i am taking min and maximum from arraylist using loop

Comment: @Akhil of course it works. A variable can **always** be immutable - you just need to assign to a new variable in a smaller scope. For better help, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) rather than a code snippet.

Comment: @BoristheSpider and/or upvote them or their comments.

Answer (score 4):

> local variables referenced from lambda expression must be final or effictively final

You can only use variables which are not changed. if it is complaining about `min`, you might need to take a copy

```
int min2 = min; // after this use min2, but don't change it.
```

Note: some IDEs have an auto-fix for this. See if you any of your variables are highlighted and the IDE might be able to correct this for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
final double max1 = max;
      final double min1 = min;
     List<Double> NormalizedData = Doublevalues1.stream().map(n -> (((((n-min1)/(max1-min1)))*2)-1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will work